# Insert SQL scripts DB Unit

Tags: dbunit

Feeling a bit embarrassed, but I cant  figure out which builder to use in DBunit to import a sql script. I only find the XML dataset builder

```
File file = new File(TEST_DATA_FILE);
FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(connection, builder.build(file));
```

Was looking through the DbUnit jar to look for something called ala SqlDateSetBuilder or similar, but didnt find anything.

Is there also a way to make DB unit export dataset to SQL scripts instead of XML ?

in advance thanks for all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was looking through the DbUnit jar to look for something called ala
>   SqlDateSetBuilder or similar, but didnt find anything.

There isn't one that I have come across. You will have to use FlatXMLDataSetBuilder.

> Is there also a way to make DB unit export dataset to SQL scripts
>   instead of XML ?

No.